# Uncaught error: Invalid type for google table column

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-visualization

I recently started using google visualization due to its simplicity. But while implementing in my recent project i seem to have run into a bit of trouble. 
The program shown is used to pull data from a JSON object and utilize it to display data in the google tables. Now as seen i have provided only a single entry in the json object to maintain simplicity. 
Now to the problem The first table used to work fine for a while , and recently completely stopped appearing. 
. Neither tables seem to appear or are displayed. The error i get in the console is the following -

Uncaught Error: Invalid type, String, for column "sitecode". in the file - http://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/abbdd6ab2d343a51d49841bf93d022fb/format+en,default+en,ui+en,table+en.I.js

The second table on the other hand does not throw errors and does not show. Also i am making the table such that only the three most recent dates of the sitecode will be displayed in the table. But i think i may have done something wrong there. Since it never worked from the beginning.
Now i cant seem to make any sense of this .Can someone point me in the right 
direction. 
thanks.

Code -

```
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
    var SiteData = SiteInfo();
    var map;
    function initialize() 
    {  
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.7200,12.5700),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
  for(m=0;m<SiteData.length;m++)
  {
    var image;
    if(SiteData[m].Connection=="Sitetype1")
    {
      image = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png";  
    }
    else if(SiteData[m].Connection=="sitetype2")
    {
      image = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png";
    }
    else
    {
        image = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png";
    }
    setmarkers(map,SiteData[m].Latitude,SiteData[m].Longitude,image)
  }
}
function setmarkers(map,lat,lon,image)
{
    var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position:latlon,icon:image});
}
function Changesite(sc)
{   
    var mpls = Outage();
    for(var i=0,numSite = SiteData.length;i<numSite;i++)
    {
        if(SiteData[i].Sitecode==sc)
        {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('String', 'sitecode');
            data.addColumn('String', SiteData[i].Sitecode);
            data.addRows([
              ['Connection', SiteData[i].Connection],
              ['Bandwidth', SiteData[i].Bandwidth],
              ['Address', SiteData[i].Address],
              ['Country', SiteData[i].Country],
                 ]);
            var chart = new google.visualization.Table

(document.getElementById('chart'));
            var options = {
                    'title': SiteData[i].Sitecode+ ' ',
                             };
            chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    }
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('String','Country');
    data1.addColumn('String','Sitecode');
    data1.addColumn('String','Outages');
    data1.addColumn('Date','Date');
    var c=0,k=0;
    mpls.sort(function(a,b){
    var c = new Date(a.date);
    var d = new Date(b.date);
    return c-d;
      });
    while(k!=3&&c<mpls.length)
    {
        if(mpls[c].SITECODE==sc)
        {
            data1.addRows(1);
            data1.setCell(k,0,mpls[i].COUNTRY);
            data1.setCell(k,1,mpls[i].SITECODE);
            data1.setCell(k,2,mpls[i].MPLSOutages);
            data1.setCell(k,3,mpls[i].DATE);
            k++;
         }
         c++;
    }
    var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById

('visualization'));
    table1.draw(data1);

}
function SiteInfo()
{
    var Siteinfo = 

[{"Connection":"Direct","Sitecode":"site1","Address":"Usa","Bandwidth":"6 

Mbps","Country":"USA","Latency":"44 ms","Latitude":44,"Longitude":34,"Item 

Type":"Item"}];
return Siteinfo();
}
function Outage()
{
    var Outage_Data= [{"COUNTRY":"USA ","SITECODE":"site1","Outage 

":"Issue1","DATE ":"4/1/2015"}];
    return Outage_Data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your row

```
data.addColumn('String', 'sitecode');
```

to

```
data.addColumn('string', 'sitecode');
```

(non capital "s" in "string"), of course this applies to all of your added columns.

Javascript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I had inadvertently changed the format of a fee rows of data. Even though I had entered numbers I had it formatted as text. Charts will not read text unless they are used as labels. Highlight the rows that aren't working and format to number or automatic! The data is now ‘valid’ to use in the chart.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30713531)